# Cannot implicitly convert type C#

Tags: c#

i have the following class:

```
public class CallbackModel : SharedModel
{
    public CallbackModel() : base()
    {

    }

    public List<Callback> getData(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {

        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        query.Append("SELECT   LAST_UPD AS PERIOD, ");
        query.Append("COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS ='Færdig' THEN 1 END) as completed, ");
        query.Append("COUNT(CASE WHEN SOLVED_SECONDS /60 /60 <= 2 THEN 1 END) as completed_within_2hours ");
        query.Append("FROM     KS_DRIFT.NYK_SIEBEL_CALLBACK_AGENT_H_V ");
        query.Append("WHERE    LAST_UPD BETWEEN '" + start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' AND '" + end.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' ");
        query.Append("AND      STATUS ='Færdig' ");
        query.Append("GROUP BY LAST_UPD ORDER BY LAST_UPD ASC");
        var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        var result = session.CreateSQLQuery(query.ToString())
            .AddEntity(typeof(Callback))
            .List<Callback>();

        return result;
    }
}
```

At the return i get the following error:

```
Error   19  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Henvendelser.Objects.Callback>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Henvendelser.Objects.Callback>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I have been looking at this for half an hour now and simply cannot see what i am missing?

Comment: Please do *not* embed values in SQL like this. Use parameterized SQL instead. And we have no idea what `session` or `sessionFactory` are...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot implicitly convert type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920422/cannot-implicitly-convert-type)

Comment: Notice, that is bad idea to name members as framework existing names.

Comment: Yes, that is SQL security attack, I could insert any information I want in your website :) (I am not hacker, I gave you an example)

Comment: Note for the people asking. It looks like he is using NHibernate, which is what the `session` and `sessionFactory` variables would be. `.List<TEntity>()` is a valid function on the query which returns an `IList<TEntity>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `IList<Callback>` return type when declare a method ?

```
public IList<Callback> getData(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
     // your code here
}
```

If you need to get exactly the List when call this method, you can also try to return:

```
return result.ToList();
```

or

```
return (List<Callback>)result;
```

Comment: I would recommend the method itself return `IList<Callback>` because that is the only guarantee that the `List<Callback>` method has based on the framework he's using - casting may break in future version of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
List<Callback>();

to

ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

What is return type of  `List<Callback>()`? I think it is return `IList<Callback>`. YOu must explicitly cast it to `List<Callback>`. You make down case which must be done explicitly.